# Linux assembly; argument list going haywire

Tags: file-io, command-line-arguments, nasm

I'm new to programming in any sort of assembly, and since I've heard that NASM-type assembly for Linux is comparatively simple to DOS based assembly, I decided to give it a try.

This is my program thus far:

```
section .data
    opening:    db  'Opening file...',10
    openingLen: equ $-opening
    opened:     db  'File opened.',10
    openedLen:  equ $-opened
    bad_params: db  'Usage: writeFile filename.ext',10
    bad_paramsLen:  equ $-bad_params
    not_opened: db  'Unable to open file.  Halted.',10
    not_openedLen:  equ $-not_opened
    hello:      db  'Hello, this is written to a file'
    helloLen:   equ $-hello
    success:    db  'Successfully wrote to file.',10
    successLen: equ $-success

section .bss
    file:       resd    1

section .text
    global _start:

_start:
    pop ebx             ; pop number of params
    test ebx,2          ; make sure there are only 2
    jne bad_param_list
    pop ebx

    mov eax,4           ; write out opening file msg
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,opening
    mov edx,openingLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,5           ; open file
    pop ebx
    mov ecx,64 
    mov edx,777o            ; permissions of file
    int 80h
    mov dword [file],eax

    test dword [file],0
    jle bad_open

    mov eax,4           ; write successful open message
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,opened
    mov edx,openedLen
    int 80h

    mov ebx,file            ; write to file (4 already in eax)
    mov ecx,hello
    mov edx,helloLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,6           ; close file
    mov ebx,file
    int 80h

    mov eax,4           ; write successfully written msg
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,success
    mov edx,successLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,1           ; exit
    mov ebx,0
    int 80h

bad_param_list:
    mov eax,4           ; write that params are bad
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,bad_params
    mov edx,bad_paramsLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,1           ; exit with code 1
    mov ebx,1
    int 80h

bad_open:
    mov eax,4           ; write that we couldn't open the file
    mov ebx,1
    mov ecx,not_opened
    mov edx,not_openedLen
    int 80h

    mov eax,1           ; exit with code 2
    mov ebx,2
    int 80h
```

The goal is to write a string of text to a file without library functions; I'm only using the Linux kernel.  I had a few problems with missing brackets here and there, and all the rest of mistakes that you'd expect from a noob to assembly, but I think this is mostly under control now.

Here's my issue:  From what I know, the first four lines of this program should pop the number of arguments off the stack, jump to `bad_param_list` if there is not only one parameter (aside from the program name), and pop the program name off the stack.

But this is not what happens.  Here's some sample I/O, reformatted for clarity:

```
$./writeFile
Opening file...
Unable to open file.  Halted.

$./writeFile x
Usage:  writeFile filename.ext

$./writeFile x x
Usage:  writeFile filename.ext

$./writeFile x x x
Opening file...
Unable to open file.  Halted.

$./writeFile x x x x
Opening file...
Unable to open file.  Halted.

$./writeFile x x x x x
Usage:  writeFile filename.ext

$./writeFile x x x x x x
Usage:  writeFile filename.ext
```

What I've noticed is that if you take the number of arguments including the name of the program, divide by 2, and discard the decimal, if the answer is odd, you'll get my usage error, but if the answer is even, you'll get the unable to open error.  This is true up until at least 10 arguments!

How the heck did I manage to do this?  And how do I get it to have the expected result?

Comment: Why do all beginning assembly programmers seem to decide they want to start by writing a complete program that works with the most bare-bones interface they can find? It is much easier, more useful, and a more transferable skill to start by writing assembler functions to link into a C program and use the existing C runtime library for I/O. I'm not saying that mastering lower-level things is _useless_ (which it isn't), but it _is_ rather more esoteric and specialized. If you call yourself a "beginner", why go for the less straightforward task without doing some basic ones first?

Comment: Here's the main reason why I made that decision.  I'm a beginner at _assembly_, not at programming in general.  I want to learn assembly because I'm interested in understanding what's at the bare-bones level.  If I want to use libraries, I'll write it in C or C++.

EDIT:  Sorry, I just realized that that could come across as a bit crass.  That's not at all what I intended.

Comment: The problem is that this way you'll end trying to teach you assembly _at the same time_ as learning usually-irrelevant details of exactly how Linux initializes processes or how syscall arguments are marshalled. In most practical cases where there is a reason to write something in assembly, you'll want to interface it with C code anyway, either inside a kernel or in an application. In contrast, learning the syscall stuff is _only ever_ going to be of _any possible_ use to you if you want to be a libc maintainer. _Leverage_ your existing C knowledge instead of _ignoring_ it!

Comment: You do make a very compelling point.  However, at this point in time, I'm interested in learning this near-lowest-level stuff just to satisfy my own interests.  I'm learning assembly right now as a way to learn the usually-irrelevant details.  It's just to satisfy my personal interests.  After I do that, and when I'm relatively fluent in the lowest levels of assembly, I'll start having my assembly interacting with C code and libraries for practical purposes.  It's just that right now, at this very moment, I'm not terribly interested in practicality :)

Comment: That's a bit like saying right now I'm interested in learning to fly a 747, at night, through a thunderstorm. Once I'm relatively fluent in the most difficult flying, I'll possibly move on to a Cessna 172 in fair weather. (Except that a 747 is a lot more mainstream and typical of "flying" than interfacing directly to syscalls is a paradigmatic "assembler" use).

Comment: Again, that is very true.  But here's an example that is closer to my view on things.  Why would someone who has no interest in flying to anywhere nor being a commercial pilot want to learn about the controls and instrumentation on World War II aircraft?  The only possible reason is that that interests the person.  I'm learning the lowest levels of assembly for the same reason that people learn the language Brainf**k:  even though it's next to useless, and even though I know I'll probably never use it for any practical purpose, it's interesting.  It's learning for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
test ebx,2
```

you want

```
cmp ebx,2
```

`test` performs a bitwise AND between the arguments and throws the result away, except for setting the flags. So, in particular ZF will be set if the two arguments have no 1-bits in positions that match. (In your particular case, this works out as setting ZF to the complement of the second-to-lowest bit of `ebx`).

Conversely `cmp` *subtracts* its arguments and throws away the result after setting flags. In that case, ZF will be set if the two arguments are *equal*.

Comment: _Sigh_.  I wish there was a good online reference or tutorial for NASM.  This seems like a very simple solution for a very simple problem.  And it works.  No more random jumping to `bad_param_list`!  Thanks so much!  I'm giving you the accepted answer now, because you answered the question, but I was wondering if you have a simple solution to this, too:  It's still giving me `Unable to open file`.  It doesn't matter whether or not the file exists.  Is this another stupid error on my part, or should i open a new question about it?  Thanks again!

Comment: It looks slightly fishy that you're popping ebx thrice without ever pushing anything, but I'm not bothering to check whether the syscall and process-initialization conventions are such that it actually makes sense!

Comment: @hennig makholm: OOhhh. It all makes perfect sense now! I was wondering how
the cmp and the jg, jl, je, jle, and jge worked. (The book i'm reading just
says that it compares the two numbers, although maybe it's because i haven't
gotten far enough in the book...) So, like if 7 > 2, then 7-2 = 5, 5 is a positive
number, so it's greater. Likewise 2 < 7, 2-7 = -5, -5 is a negitive number, so it's
less, and 2 = 2, 2-2 = 0, it's 0 so it's the same. Sorry for the wierd comment, it
just feels good to finally understand.

Comment: @George: Yes, though there are some subtleties connected with making sure that the comparisons work correctly even if the subtraction overflows, so actually the conditional jumps check the carry/borrow flag (or overflow) flag instead of (or in addition to) the sign bit.